quote about white family happy to living in carboard box if black family does not have box?
I'm trying to find a quote that asserts something along the lines of a poor white American family will be happy to live in a cardboard box under a bridge as long as there is a black family without the cardboard box beneath them.
I have it in my head that was originally said by either Upton Sinclair or H. L. Mencken, but of course that could be wrong, but I have a strong feeling it was at least someone in that "class" and time period - maybe Thurber, Sinclair Lewis, Steinbeck... although really Upton Sinclair or Mencken seems the most likely sources for that sentiment.

Are you certain of those sources? I had a quick look at well-known quotes from both and nothing like this stood out.

I''m not certain about those sources, it could very well be someone else 'in that class'  and time period - Thurber, Sinclair Lewis, someone like that. I will update question

Related to LBJ? https://lakithatolbert.medium.com/president-lyndon-b-f21459f7b3e2   and elsewhere ... https://www.quora.com/Was-Lyndon-Johnson-right-when-he-said-If-you-can-convince-the-lowest-white-man-hes-better-than-the-best-colored-man-he-wont-notice-youre-picking-his-pocket  Search for "lowest white man"

yes you are probably right that it's that one.

@shoover Why not make that an answer?
